# Zooming 2d plots in Mathematica 11

Tags: plotting

I've seen this question many times but thought I'd ask it about Mathematica 11 specifically. I'm new to Mathematica and I'm just creating some simple plots with ListLinePlot. I'd like to be able to zoom/pan the plots using the mouse. Is there a way to do this which is built into Mathematica 11?

Comment: Please link questions you have in mind.

Comment: No, Mathematica 11 does not bring anything new in this area for plots.  (It does for GeoGraphics and for Images, but not for general Graphics)  Any other discussions you may have seen on this topic are still relevant.

Comment: I guess it might be too subjective for stackexchange but something like "yes, that's a common frustration new Mathematica users have, but the functionality is not built-in perhaps for this or that reason and here's how people tend to work with plots in Mathematica so you can see why this seemingly basic functionality hasn't been added yet" was what I was hoping for (well actually I was hoping the feature would be there in v11 but anyway) :)